# Apache JMeter Load Testing - Load test over certain period of time

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I want to load test my web application using JMeter, previously I load test multiple times. But I want to load test it for certain period.
**Example:** I want to hit or load test it for 1000 requests within time limit of 1 hour.
Simply, 1000 requests should triggered within 1 hour not more than that or not less than that time. 
Is this possible in JMeter or is there any additional plugin for the same? 
What JMeter configurations should I keep for this scenario like thread and loop count etc.?

I tried by giving duration time but my web application able to server that much requests within 20 minutes only. 
I want to check for 1hr with same no of requests. 
What JMeter configurations should I do for this scenario like thread and loop count etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to limit the number of requests to 1000 - use [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller):

[image]

---

In case you want to evenly distribute 1000 request across 1 hour: the easiest is going for [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer), the appropriate configuration would be:

[image]

Another option is [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-throughput)

[image]

The value of `16,666666666666667` requests per minute calculated as follows:

```
1000 requests per hour / 60 minutes per hour
```

Loop count needs in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to be set to `-1` or you need to tick `Forever`

The number of threads - it's the question to you, it should be **sufficient** for generating 17 requests per minute.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this approach.
I tried with same way, but I used constant timer instead, it is also working after adding think time in milliseconds.